# In the document it puts all the paragraphs in format and size specific PYWIN32

Tags: python, pywin32

In the word document all the paragraphs appear in format and size, I only want it to change the bold format and size in the paragraphs that have ## or ###. In the cmd I get this:

EXAMPLE MARKDOWN (Title)

These are examples to see where it falls.♂♂♂Hello, it falls here, you see, hahaha xD

4th level markdown example (title)

Hello♂♂It is a curious and beautiful example as well. ♂♂ It's a good day hahaha. ♂♂ Greetings.

♀

Paragraphs appear on a single line instead of separate ones plus it applies formatting to all other unrelated paragraphs.

The script works correctly on the other hand it handles special fields called citation and bibliography.

```py
import win32com.client
imports

print("Starting the Word application and opening the document...")

# Initialize the Word application and open the document
word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word_app.Visible = True

file_path = os.path.abspath("generated_document.docx")
doc = word_app.Documents.Open(file_path)

# Define the target text and replacement text
target_text_1 = "###"
replacement_text_1 = ""
target_text_2 = "##"
replacement_text_2 = ""

# Use the Find object to search the entire document
find_object = doc.Content.Find
find_object.ClearFormatting()

# Find all paragraphs that contain "###" and save their text
print("Searching for '###' in document...")
found_paragraphs_1 = []
find_object.Text = target_text_1
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
     if target_text_1 in paragraph.Range.Text:
         found_paragraphs_1.append(paragraph.Range.Text)

# Perform the replacement of "###" with " "
if found_paragraphs_1:
     print("Replacing '###' with ' '...")
     find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
     find_object.Replacement.Text = replacement_text_1
     find_object.Execute(Replace=2) # 2 = wdReplaceAll
     print(f"Replaced text: {target_text_1} -> {replacement_text_1}")

# Apply bold formatting to paragraphs where "###" has been removed
print("Applying formatting to paragraphs that contained '###'...")
for found_text in found_paragraphs_1:
     print(f"Paragraph found: {found_text}")
     for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
         if found_text.replace(target_text_1, replacement_text_1) == paragraph.Range.Text:
             print("Applying Bold format and font size 11...")
             paragraph.Range.Bold = True
             paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 11
             print(f"Paragraph is now Bold and font size 11. Paragraph text: {paragraph.Range.Text}")
             break

# Find all paragraphs that contain "##" and save their text
print("Searching for '##' in document...")
found_paragraphs_2 = []
find_object.Text = target_text_2
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
     if target_text_2 in paragraph.Range.Text:
         found_paragraphs_2.append(paragraph.Range.Text)

# Perform the replacement of "##" by " "
if found_paragraphs_2:
     print("Replacing '##' with ' '...")
     find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
     find_object.Replacement.Text = replacement_text_2
     find_object.Execute(Replace=2) # 2 = wdReplaceAll
     print(f"Replaced text: {target_text_2} -> {replacement_text_2}")

# Apply bold formatting to paragraphs where "##" has been removed
print("Applying formatting to paragraphs that contained '##'...")
for found_text in found_paragraphs_2:
     print(f"Paragraph found: {found_text}")
     for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
         if found_text.replace(target_text_2, replacement_text_2) == paragraph.Range.Text:
             print("Applying Bold format and font size 16...")
             paragraph.Range.Bold = True
             paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 16
             print(f"Paragraph is now in Bold format and font size 16. Paragraph text: {paragraph.Range.Text}")
             break

# Print the entire content of the document, paragraph by paragraph
print("Printing the document content...")
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
     print(paragraph.Range.Text + '\r\n')

# Save and close the document
print("Saving and closing the document...")
doc.Save()
doc.Close()
word_app.Quit()

print("Done!")
```

In the cmd I get this:

EXAMPLE MARKDOWN (Title)

These are examples to see where it falls.♂♂♂Hello, it falls here, you see, hahaha xD

4th level markdown example (title)

Hello♂♂It is a curious and beautiful example as well. ♂♂ It's a good day hahaha. ♂♂ Greetings.

♀

I wanted this result:

EXAMPLE MARKDOWN (Title)

These are examples to see where it falls. (Bold and size 16)
♂♂♂Hello, it falls here, you see, hahaha xD

4th level markdown example (title)

hello♂♂
It is a curious and beautiful example as well.
♂♂ It's a good day hahaha. (Bold and size11)
♂♂ Greetings.

Thank you, I trust you can explain it to me well. The failure is surely a silly failure.

Answer (score 0):

You first run this with pywin32:

remember that you must import win32com.client

```
# Replace "↵" with "^p" in the document
print("Replacing '↵' with '^p' in the document...")
find_object = doc.Content.Find
find_object.ClearFormatting()
find_object.Text = '^l' # '^l' is the code for '↵'
find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
find_object.Replacement.Text = '^p' # '^p' is the code for '¶'
find_object.Execute(Replace=2) # 2 = wdReplaceAll
```

Then you can execute the following for the pads. Remember everything with pywin32. It is only for windows.

```
# Define the target text and replacement text
target_text_1 = "###"
replacement_text_1 = ""
target_text_2 = "##"
replacement_text_2 = ""

# Use the Find object to search the entire document
find_object = doc.Content.Find
find_object.ClearFormatting()

# Find all paragraphs that contain "###" and save their text
print("Searching for '###' in document...")
found_paragraphs_1 = []
find_object.Text = target_text_1
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
     if target_text_1 in paragraph.Range.Text:
         found_paragraphs_1.append(paragraph.Range.Text)

# Perform the replacement of "###" with " "
if found_paragraphs_1:
     print("Replacing '###' with ' '...")
     find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
     find_object.Replacement.Text = replacement_text_1
     find_object.Execute(Replace=2) # 2 = wdReplaceAll
     print(f"Replaced text: {target_text_1} -> {replacement_text_1}")

# Apply bold formatting to paragraphs where "###" has been removed
print("Applying formatting to paragraphs that contained '###'...")
for found_text in found_paragraphs_1:
     print(f"Paragraph found: {found_text}")
     for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
         if found_text.replace(target_text_1, replacement_text_1) == paragraph.Range.Text:
             print("Applying Bold format and font size 11...")
             paragraph.Range.Bold = True
             paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 11
             print(f"Paragraph is now Bold and font size 11. Paragraph text: {paragraph.Range.Text}")
             break

# Find all paragraphs that contain "##" and save their text
print("Searching for '##' in document...")
found_paragraphs_2 = []
find_object.Text = target_text_2
for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
     if target_text_2 in paragraph.Range.Text:
         found_paragraphs_2.append(paragraph.Range.Text)

# Perform the replacement of "##" by " "
if found_paragraphs_2:
     print("Replacing '##' with ' '...")
     find_object.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
     find_object.Replacement.Text = replacement_text_2
     find_object.Execute(Replace=2) # 2 = wdReplaceAll
     print(f"Replaced text: {target_text_2} -> {replacement_text_2}")

# Apply bold formatting to paragraphs where "##" has been removed
print("Applying formatting to paragraphs that contained '##'...")
for found_text in found_paragraphs_2:
     print(f"Paragraph found: {found_text}")
     for paragraph in doc.Paragraphs:
         if found_text.replace(target_text_2, replacement_text_2) == paragraph.Range.Text:
             print("Applying Bold format and font size 16...")
             paragraph.Range.Bold = True
             paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 16
             print(f"Paragraph is now in Bold format and font size 16. Paragraph text: {paragraph.Range.Text}")
             break
```

To start this app you can put this, for example:

```
import win32com.client
imports

print("Starting the Word application and opening the document...")

# Initialize the Word application and open the document
word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word_app.Visible = True
```

If you want to save in pywin32 you put this:

```
print("Saving and closing the document...")
doc.Save()
doc.Close()
word_app.Quit()
print("Done!")
```